# Can hash set internally use some other collection instead of hash map

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashset

Why is it like Hash set internally only used Hash map ? Is it something related with performance?

Comment: No, it is because of the name. If it used something else it would not be called `HashSet`.

Answer (score 1):

A HashSet can be thought of as a special case of a HashMap in which you don't actually care about the type of values, only whether a value is associated with a particular key.

So, it made sense to just implement one on top of the other.
A HashMap is a good choice if your key type has a good hash function.

Similarly, TreeSet is implemented using TreeMap, which can be effective if your keys are ordered/comparable.

You can implement the Set interface in many other ways, but these are the typical ones.

Answer (score 0):

Nah, it's just convenient, and not actually any less efficient on most VMs.  So Java -- at least in some implementations -- doesn't bother doing anything fancier.

Answer (score 0):

Since HashMap and HashSet are basicly using the same algorithm, it is simpler not to implement it twice, and therefore it isn't surprising that a few, if not all, JVM implementation do it.
It is also doable with LinkedHashMap/Set, TreeMap/Set and others.

More generally, it is possible to create any Set implementation from any Map implementation by choosing the value as being the same as the key, or be a constant.
The loss in memory storage is negligible.

By the way, the JDK provides a `Collections.newSetFromMap` method which does exactly this: it converts a `Map<E,Boolean>` into a `Set<E>` by mapping all keys to `Boolean.TRUE`. When there is no corresponding `Set` implementation to a Map one, this utility method is very useful, for example for ConcurrentHashMap.

The opposite, creating a Map implementation from a `Set` one, is also doable, though it's slightly more difficult.